# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT with multiple JOINS

Tags: mysql, select, join, distinct

I'm trying to SELECT, and get a unique result set, from a MySQL database, as shown below. My problem is, I think, I don't understand LEFT Joins well enough. Or, maybe I need to use a different Join approach.

Here's a description of the database.

tbAdult (Adults) have x number of tbchild (Children) , and uses a cross-ref table called tbadultchildxref. This table has an f-key to both Adult and Child. I have to use an x-ref table, because there's a many-to-many relationship between these two tables, and there's other data that's keep in the x-ref, which I have removed for simplicity.

In turn, each Child belongs to a Program (tblprogram).

Each Program has x number of Cameras (tblCamera). Again, I have to use an x-ref table between tblProgram and tblCamera due to a many-to-many relationship, and other reasons.

What I am trying to get at, is a unique list of Cameras for a given Parent.

For example, Parent 675 has three children, Child ID's 789,788, and 789. Those three children, in turn, belong to Program ID's 4, 5, and 6.

Program ID 4 has Camera ID's 1,2,3
Program ID 5 has Camera ID's 4,5,6
Program ID 6 has Camera ID's 1,6,7,8

What I would like the result set to be is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

I have tried different combinations of SELECT DISTINCT, LEFT JOINS on the various x-ref tables, etc. but I just can't seem to get it.

My other problem, along the way, is I need to check the "Active" fields in Adult, Child, and Program to equal = 1 (true) for the result set.

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbladult` (
 `pkAdultID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fldAdultActive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
 `fldAdultLogin` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fldAdultPassword` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fldAdultFirstName` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fldAdultLastName` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pkAdultID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


/*Table structure for table `tblchild` */

CREATE TABLE `tblchild` (
 `pkChildID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fldChildActive` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fldChildFirstName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fldChildLastName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fkChildProgram` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pkChildID`),
 KEY `FK_tblchild` (`fkChildProgram`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_tblchild` FOREIGN KEY (`fkChildProgram`) REFERENCES `tblprogram` (`pkProgramID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


/*Table structure for table `tbladultchildxref` */

CREATE TABLE `tbladultchildxref` (
 `pkAdultChildxRefID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fldAdultChildxRefActive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
 `fkAdultID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fkChildID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pkAdultChildxRefID`),
 KEY `FK_tbladultchildxref` (`fkAdultID`),
 KEY `FK_tbladultchildxref2` (`fkChildID`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_tbladultchildxref` FOREIGN KEY (`fkAdultID`) REFERENCES `tbladult` (`pkAdultID`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_tbladultchildxref2` FOREIGN KEY (`fkChildID`) REFERENCES `tblchild` (`pkChildID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



/*Table structure for table `tblprogram` */

CREATE TABLE `tblprogram` (
  `pkProgramID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fldProgamActive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `fldProgramName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkProgramID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Table structure for table `tblcamera` */

CREATE TABLE `tblcamera` (
 `pkCameraID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fldCameraName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fldCameralocation` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fldCameraURL` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pkCameraID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


/*Table structure for table `tblprogramcameraxref` */

CREATE TABLE `tblprogramcameraxref` (
 `pkProgramCameraXrefID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fkProgramID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fkCameraID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pkProgramCameraXrefID`),
 KEY `FK_tblprogramcameraxref` (`fkProgramID`),
 KEY `FK_camerasforprograms` (`fkCameraID`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_camerasforprograms` FOREIGN KEY (`fkCameraID`) REFERENCES `tblcamera`     (`pkCameraID`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_tblprogramcameraxref` FOREIGN KEY (`fkProgramID`) REFERENCES `tblprogram` (`pkProgramID`)
```

Comment: Adding the SQL you're executing would be useful for others to help you.

Comment: Helpful Tool of many types of Joins found [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No LEFT JOINs necessary:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblprogramcameraxref.fkcameraid
FROM tblprogramcameraxref
JOIN tblprogram ON tblprogramcameraxref.fkprogramid = tblprogram.pkprogramid
  AND tblprobram.fldProgramActive = 1
JOIN tblchild ON tblprogramcameraxref.fkprogramid = tblchild.fkchildprogram 
  AND tblchild.fldChildActive = 1
JOIN tbladultchildxref ON tblchild.pkchildid = tbladultchildxref.fkchildid
  AND tbladultchildxref.fldAdultChildxRefActive = 1
WHERE tbladultchildxref.fkadultid = 675
```

Also, you may want to check the `fkChildProgram int(1) DEFAULT NULL,` in tblchild - the column it references is defined as `int(11)`

At this point you shouldn't really need to check if Adult is active (since that's the search criteria you started with), but if you must - just add this to the end of the join list:

```
JOIN tbladult ON tbladultchildxref.fkadultid = tbladult.pkadultid
  AND tbladult.fldAdultActive = 1
```

Comment: +1 - beat me to it.  Might want to add a `AND fldChildActive = 1 AND fldProgramActive = 1` to the WHERE clause as well.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, and also, pointing out the faults in my column definition. I can see now, the logic of looking at my schema from a bottom-to-top approach. Now I can see where the multiple, but simple JOIN ON work. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It is a long description. If I have understood the question correctly this query should help you -

```
SELECT DISTINCT pcref.fkCameraID
FROM tbladult adult,
     tblchild child,
     tbladultchildxref acref,
     tblprogram prog,
     tblcamera camera,
     tblprogramcameraxref pcref
WHERE adult.pkAdultID = 675
AND adult.fldAdultActive = TRUE
AND adult.pkAdultID = acref.fkAdultID
AND acref.fkChildID = child.pkChildID 
AND child.fldChildActive = TRUE
AND child.fkChildProgram = prog.pkProgramID 
AND prog.fldProgamActive = TRUE
AND prog.pkProgramID = pcref.fkProgramID
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Actually, this solution had two very cool things about it. For one, it was done in the same order as the way I have my schema, or in other words, a top-down approach. And two, this did not use any JOINS at all. In the end, I went with one of the other answers, but I thought this was a great answer, too. Since I am a newbie in SQL, and still trying to learn when to use different JOINS, I wanted to force myself to fully understand all the options given. However, in some case in the future, I will keep this very straight forward approach in mind, as well.

Comment: @TimMurphree I feel JOINS are good but when you can achieve things in a more simple way then why to go for complicated ones. ;-)

Comment: @TimMurphree there most certainly are JOINs in the above query, albeit implicit.  Using `SELECT ... FROM table1, table2` is in fact a CROSS JOIN between table1 and table2.  Adding `WHERE table1.key1 = table2.key2` turns it into a conventional `INNER JOIN`.